# Sigmoid tensorflow computational graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, sigmoid

What am i doing wrong here? The equation and data are pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

look at line:

```
 yhat = c/1+tf.math.exp(-x*p)
```

This is the equivalent of y = c + e^(-x*p), which is not a sigmoid, it's an exponential plus constant.

You probably want:

```
yhat = c/(1+tf.math.exp(-x*p))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but now it looks like this
https://imgur.com/a/KPEPhVd